# Splitting JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, materialize

I have a problem with initialization of plugins. Everything is working except few plugins from materialize -  http://materializecss.com/

google maps, ul.tabs, parrallax and slider are not working when put in single .js document.

I had resolved this problem by putting owl-carousel code and ul.tabs code in separate document, so that i had init.js, initCarousel.js and initTab.js. When those 2 parts of code are in separate document, all plugins and all code behaves normally

script tags are defined before closing of the /body tag

```
//Javascript
function overlaycontactopen() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}
function overlaycontactclose() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}

function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("formular").submit();
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function initMap() {
    var uluru = {
        lat: 44,
        lng: 44
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(uluru);
    });
}

// JQUERY
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.rotate = function (degrees) {
        return $(this).css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
        });
    };
    $('.strijela').click(function() {
        var rotation = $(this).find("i").data('rotation') || 0;
        rotation += 180;
        $(this).children("i").rotate(rotation).data('rotation', rotation);
        $(this).next(".ekstenzijapanel").slideToggle("slow");
    });

//MATERIALIZE STUFF
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplayHoverPause:false,
        items: 1,   
        autoHeight: true,
        autoHeightClass: 'owl-height'
    });
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    $('.parallax').parallax();
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('.slider').slider({
        height: 689,
        indicators: false,
    });
});
```

Comment: show your full source code

Comment: This IS full JS code

Comment: _"not working"_ is not a useful problem statement.  Do you see any errors etc?

Comment: https://jedantest.000webhostapp.com/Stranice/EN/index.html
Here is the test site

Comment: maybe it's me, but i fail to see a question here; "I had resolved this problem". Do you really need to assemble it again in one file if working in separate ones? is this the question? Also this part is not really precise "by putting owl-carousel code and ul.tabs code in separate document", do you mean the plugin source code, or the calls to them?

Comment: Try putting all of the "google maps, ul.tabs, parrallax and slider" in a single file before closing of </head> section of the document. And leave the code you posted as is, before closing of body. Check your errors in console to see what's going on if needed.

Comment: I am sorry for my english.
I mean the calls for them. Source code of those plugins are intact. I would like to assemble them since i don't know how using different files to call different plugins would affect performance of the website

Comment: @HunterFrazier I did what you said, and the problem persists. The only thing that seems to have changed something is when i remove "owl-carousel" part of code. Then everything except the "ul.tabs" work.

Comment: One thing to look at: do any of the separate script files have `"use strict"` near the top, outside of any function scope? If so, that can lead to problems if you merge with other scripts that expect sloppy mode and suddenly run in strict mode as well.